# How to fix the rowCount problem in react-virtualized (infinite loader)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-virtualized, rowcount

I'm setting up a react-virtualized Infinite loader in my project but i have a little problem. So i haven't got the remoteRowCount so i found one solution, like this:

```
public rowCount = this.props.hasNextPage ? this.props.list.length + 1 : this.props.list.length;
```

But this doesn't work for me. I tried to debug why not working , but i dont found nothing.

p

```
public rowCount = this.props.hasNextPage ? this.props.list.length + 1 : this.props.list.length; 

<InfiniteLoader
        rowCount={this.rowCount}
        isRowLoaded={({ index }) => !!this.props.list[index]}
        loadMoreRows={this.props.loadMoreRows}
        minimumBatchSize={10}
        threshold={5}
      >
        {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
          <WindowScroller>
            {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (
              <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                {({ width }) => (
                  <List
                    ref={list => {
                      this.listRef = list;
                      registerChild(list);
                    }}
                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                    autoHeight
                    width={width}
                    height={height}
                    rowCount={this.props.list.length}
                    rowHeight={56}
                    rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                    overscanRowCount={0}
                    isScrolling={isScrolling}
                    onScroll={onChildScroll}
                    scrollTop={scrollTop}
                  />
                )}
              </AutoSizer>
            )}
          </WindowScroller>
        )}
      </InfiniteLoader>
```

Comment: Could you please create a minimum reproducible example in a codepen?

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed**, but i want to help for you (if you have a similar problem)

First off all try to understand why not work correct. For me it has been worked correct with a arbitrary big number, but with rowCount it isn't work.

In my project case:

- First i get an initial list (componentDidMount).
- Second, i figure out when i add a random number to the rowCount, it was almost good.
- Third, i tried to debug the loadMoreRows, i started with **indexRange**. Tadaaa, this is the problem. For me the **startIndex** and the **stopIndex** it was exact same value. So i tried to figure out why? And I found, because the rowCount calculator expression get the previous value, not the present value.

*Sorry for linguistic errors*